# Build an open source project from github (not mine) with a ci

Tags: github, build, continuous-integration, fork, webhooks

There is an open source project (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), which I would like to get built using travis/circleci or another cloud ci. However, those CI's don't allow you to get to repos that are not yours.

I didn't try, but I have a hunch that I won't be able to get a webhook setup as well to get notified when those repos 'master' branch is updated.

Why not fork ? Because then I somehow need to manually\use cron server to get my forked repo updated! It loses the point of having open source repo builds...

Why do I want to build it continually? Because they do not upload their .aar output to mavencetral or jcenter and I don't want to put the .aars in my project and get it updated all the time - bloats the repo...

In any case, I don't get it - there's an open source project, the repo exists and open to everyone, pulling the data and getting webhooks doesn't compromise that repo in any way why isn't this possible ????

If I'm mistaken and web hook is possible, how can I set up a build that will end up in uploading to mavencentral (probably gradle plugin, I have an account and be happy to have a public copy there)?

(I thought of micro service, free of course of some kind + docker based ci which I can pull and build whatever, I don't mind if a build will take time).

Comment: You can fork the repo, configure Travis build and propose a PR to the upstream. They might accept it.

Comment: might or might not, this is not a solution.

Comment: What about polling option? For example free version of TeamCity supports that out of the box.

Comment: i have either circleci or travis at my disposal currently, i might be able to get a nice free account for shippable or something of that sort, but they all work on webhooks, i thought of using a micro service like amazon lambda to check get the webhook and call travis\circlci api

Comment: You can create an issue to add CI to the project and host the files you are looking for. Seems like good practice anyways.